# how to sort date in descending order using comparator

Tags: java, sorting, date, datetime, dictionary

I have a bean object `testBean` with getter setter and methods.I am retrieving the results from the database and storing it in a `TreeMap`

The Output of the `Map` will look like this:

```
{Student1 = [testBean[Dept=Science,ID=12,grade=A,Date=12-Jan-2013]]
            [testBean[Dept=Science,ID=12,grade=B,Date=14-Mar-2013]]

{Student2 = [testBean[Dept=Science,ID=02,grade=A,Date=12-Jan-2013]]
            [testBean[Dept=Science,ID=02,grade=A,Date=14-Mar-2013]]
```

I need the Output to be arranged in Descending order so that the latest date comes first. So I am using a comparator to sort the date:

```
public int DateCompare(Object studentObj, Object anotherStudentObj) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String value = ((testBean) studentObj).getDateTmTrans();
    String value1 = ((testBean) anotherStudentObj).getDateTmTrans();
    int retVal = 0;

    try {

        Date firstDate = dateFormat.parse(value);
        Date secondDate = dateFormat.parse(value1);     
        retVal = firstDate.compareTo(secondDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

But I couldn't able to sort the date in descending order. Is there any solution to get the desired output?

Any suggestions are welcome

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> But i couldn't able to sort the date in descending order.

Two easy options:

- You could just reverse your comparison yourself, using `secondDate.compareTo(firstDate)`. (I assume that in your real code you're actually returning `retVal`; it's ignored in your posted code.)
- Call [`Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder-java.util.Comparator-) to create a comparator with the reverse order of the original one.

Comment: Apologies to everyone for asking a silly question.Actually i made a mistake in my code where retVal is not returned.Thanks @Jon Skeet for pointing out..I haven't edited my code.Some one from the forum can close this topic as it doesn't serve any purpose to the viewer in the forum..Thanks and apologies everyone..

Comment: @jegadees: So do you mean your problem was nothing to do with being in descending order, and everything to do with the comparator just being broken to start with? (I would also *strongly* advise you to store the dates as `Date` or `Calendar` values rather than strings, by the way. Why parse all the time?)

Comment: Yes.There is nothing wrong with the descending order.The broken link in the comparator where the retVal is not returned caused the problem.I agree with your solution on storing as dates.Will implement the same here.Thanks a lot

Comment: AH , all the answers seems to be perfect.but i cant mark all of them..So upvoting..Thanks guys

Comment: @jegadees FYI, both Joda-Time and java.time libraries offer a `LocalDate` class to represent this kind of data, a date without a time-of-day.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of comparing `firstDate` against `secondDate`, compare `secondDate` against `firstDate`:

```java
retVal = secondDate.compareTo(firstDate);
```

And don't forget to return `retVal` instead of `0` ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could add a boolean parameter to your comparator's constructor, e.g. `boolean descending` and then do this:

```
retVal = (descending ? -1 : 1) * firstDate.compareTo(secondDate);
```

here, if you created your comparator by passing true as "descending" argument, it would flip the sign around, leave 0 unaffected, and effectively you'd end up with a comparator that is easily configurable to help you ordering dates in ascending/descending order.

Comment: As I noted on another (now deleted answer): This fails if firstDate.compareTo(secondDate) returns Integer.MIN_VALUE. It's a known broken way of reversing an ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
static final Comparator<All_Request_data_dto> byDate
    = new Comparator<All_Request_data_dto>() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

    public int compare(All_Request_data_dto ord1, All_Request_data_dto ord2) {
        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;
        try {
            d1 = sdf.parse(ord1.lastModifiedDate);
            d2 = sdf.parse(ord2.lastModifiedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? -1 : 1);     //descending
    //  return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? 1 : -1);     //ascending
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Are there any advantages compared to the other answers?